# M2 Update product via API

Tags: magento2

We would like to update the following fields of a product via the M2 API

- Product description
- Meta title
- Meta description

Which API would we use?

Answer (score 0):

Do a **PUT** to  -

```
rest/V1/products/xxxx
```

Where **xxxx** is the SKU of the product you want to update.

An example body would be -

```
{

    "product":{
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "description",
            "value": "This is the description I want to update"
        }
        ]

}
}
```

If you want a list of the values that can be changed, refer to the [swagger documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index.html) or do a **GET** to the products SKU.